# How do I translate or convert LISP code into C code?

Tags: c, lisp

I really don't like LISP and I would love to convert all the old lisp code into c. I am a beginning C coder and even more of a beginner with lisp.

Comment: Any specific dialect of LISP?  Why do you want to convert the LISP to C?  How good are you with lists?

Comment: koza style lisp trees used in genetic programming (www.genetic-programming.org).  i want to finish my genetic programming problem and then convert the final solution from a lisp tree in to c code, i am not that good with lists (what kinds of lists?)

Comment: When LISP doesn't stand for 'Lots of Irritating Silly Parentheses', it is short for LISt Processing.  The whole language is built around processing lists.  My gut feel is you'd be better off working in LSIP and not trying to convert to C.

Comment: Are you looking how to write yours compiler?

Comment: You can try using GCL with its C backend. But, of course, it would not be a readable C code.

Answer (score 4):

The two languages are *extremely* different. Lisp depends on the existence of a great deal of machinery:

- code to parse and evaluate Lisp code
- a standard list data structure with particular semantics
- a garbage collector

And C, of course, has none of these things. By the time you collect all these things together and make them available in C, you'll have a complex, difficult-to-understand programming environment. It would be a lot easier to just learn Lisp!

Comment: i only took the basic compiler course in undergrad and it was really hard for me,  i know you could never do it 100% but i just want to know if any partial solutions exist, if the target code is a koza-genetic-programming lisp-tree would that make it eaiser to convert to C code?

Comment: There are genetic programming libraries for C/C++; implementing the same thing in C would be easier than directly trying to *translate* the Lisp.

Comment: Also, there is a compiler called [Stalin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalin_(Scheme_implementation)) that can translate Lisp code into optimized C code.

Answer (score 1):

This is some LISP that I converted into C.  The LISP is from ['Calendrical Calculations'](http://www.calendarists.com/), and the conversion was done long enough ago to be from the 'Millenium Edition' of the book (there's now a Third Edition which you'd get instead), so all the names in the C are prefixed with 'CCME' or 'ccme'.

```
/*
Gregorian year corresponding to the fixed $date$.

Original LISP code
(defun alt-gregorian-year-from-fixed (date)
  ;; TYPE fixed-date -> gregorian-year
  (let* ((approx ; approximate year
          (quotient (- date gregorian-epoch -2)
                    146097/400))
         (start  ; start of next year
          (+ gregorian-epoch
             (* 365 approx)
             (quotient approx 4)
             (- (quotient approx 100))
             (quotient approx 400))))
    (if (< date start)
        approx
      (1+ approx))))

*/

CCME_GregorianYear ccme_alt_gregorian_year_from_fixed(CCME_FixedDate date)
{
        CCME_GregorianYear rv;
        /*S-CODE*/
        CCME_GregorianYear approx = ccme_quotient(date - ccme_gregorian_epoch() + 2, 146097.0/400.0);
        CCME_GregorianYear start = ccme_gregorian_epoch() + (365 * approx) +
                     ccme_quotient(approx, 4) -
                     ccme_quotient(approx, 100) +
                     ccme_quotient(approx, 400);

        if  (date < start)
                rv = approx;
        else
                rv = approx + 1;
        /*E-CODE*/
        return rv;
}
```

However, this is not typical LISP (nor particularly typical C), and the general conversion of LISP into C is anything but trivial.  This would be doubly true when you're dealing with strings and lists (especially of lists of strings) as the memory management in C becomes...interesting (hard work, problematic).